# How to select a option from drop down with div tag/class?.selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, tags, dropdown

I have tried all the possible things. also, tried searching over tried different combinations and variations. I can get the element clicked which opens the dropdown. but i am not able to select an option in it. I tried with actions, sendkeys, keys.down/enter and multiple things as well. however, it didn't help. That's the only thing I am stuck on.

//selecting office

1.driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).click();

Actions actions = new Actions(driver); actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="DG5QEPn"]/div/div/div1/div1"))).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).click();

driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys("RTP HQ"); driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys(Keys.Down); driver.findElement(By.id("DG5QEPn")).sendKeys(Keys.Enter);

Html-
In the below image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me

WebElement selectMyElement = driver.findElement(this.getObject(By.Id("Id of Your DropDown")));
selectMyElement.click();

Actions keyDown = new Actions(driver);
keyDown.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.DOWN, Keys.DOWN, Keys.ENTER)).perform();

Answer (score 2):

You should enumerate through all of the options then click on the one you want. See [What is the correct way to select an `<option>` using Selenium's Python WebDriver](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver).

> The easiest way that I have found was to do something along the lines of:
>
> ```
> el = driver.find_element_by_id('id_of_select')
> for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
>     if option.text == 'The Options I Am Looking For':
>         option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
>         break
> ```